# python and pygame image movement

Tags: python, animation, pygame

Ok so my code is below, right now I'm new to pygame and trying to figure out how to move images on the screen. From what I've seen of pygame the following code should move the image up(the only possible movement right now). However when I push up the image doesn't move. Python is recognizing that I'm pushing up because it prints in the system tray, however there is just no movement, can someone help?

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

FPS = 30


WIN_WIDTH = 800
WIN_HEIGHT = 600
HALF_WIDTH = int(WIN_WIDTH / 2)
HALF_HEIGHT = int(WIN_HEIGHT / 2)

COLOR = (255, 0, 255)
IMAGE = pygame.image.load('squirrel.png')
STARTSIZE = 25

LEFT = 'left'

def main():
    pygame.init()
    FPS_CLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
    movement = 1

    moveUp = False

    DISPLAY_SURFACE = pygame.display.set_mode((WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT))

    while True:
        DISPLAY_SURFACE.fill(COLOR)

        playerObj = {'surface': pygame.transform.scale(IMAGE, (STARTSIZE, STARTSIZE)),
                     'facing': LEFT,
                     'size': STARTSIZE,
                     'x': HALF_WIDTH,
                     'y': HALF_HEIGHT}

        playerObj['rect'] = pygame.Rect( (playerObj['x'], playerObj['y'], playerObj['size'], playerObj['size']) )
        DISPLAY_SURFACE.blit(playerObj['surface'], playerObj['rect'])


        for event in pygame.event.get():

            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_UP:
                    moveUp = True

            if event.type == KEYUP:
                if event.key == K_UP:
                    moveUp = False

            elif event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

        if moveUp:
            playerObj['y'] += movement
            print("moving up")

        else:
            print('stopped')

        pygame.display.update()
        FPS_CLOCK.tick(FPS)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a new playerObj each time it iterates through the while loop so you're not going to see it move (as it is setting it's 'y' value to HALF_HEIGHT each time). Move the playerObj definition out of the while loop.

Comment: I tried that there still isn't any movement, I figured that was probably my problem earlier but either way it doesn't move the image

Comment: Well that *is* one part of the problem. The other might be to do with your blit order, unfortunately I can't test right at the moment. Try moving DISPLAY_SURFACE.fill(color) and DISPLAY_SURFACE.blit(..) to just before pygame.display.update()

Comment: Oh I got it, thanks for the suggestions! I actually needed to move playerObj out of the while but keep the playerObj in the while loop, its working now though thank you!

Comment: Glad it's working. Yes, you're correct you should keep the playerObj['rect'] = pygame.rect() call in the while loop and just the playerObj definition outside (as per my answer ;)).

Answer (score 0):

You must create the playerObj before you enter the while-loop, and then only draw it to the `DISPLAY_SURFACE` each time. Also, increasing the key `y` of your dictionary won't help, you must modify the `rect` instead. A minimally invasive solution would be:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

FPS = 30


WIN_WIDTH = 800
WIN_HEIGHT = 600
HALF_WIDTH = int(WIN_WIDTH / 2)
HALF_HEIGHT = int(WIN_HEIGHT / 2)

COLOR = (255, 0, 255)
IMAGE = pygame.image.load('squirrel.png')
STARTSIZE = 25

LEFT = 'left'

def main():
    pygame.init()
    FPS_CLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
    movement = 1

    moveUp = False

    DISPLAY_SURFACE = pygame.display.set_mode((WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT))

    playerObj = {'surface': pygame.transform.scale(IMAGE, (STARTSIZE, STARTSIZE)),
                     'facing': LEFT,
                     'size': STARTSIZE,
                     'x': HALF_WIDTH,
                     'y': HALF_HEIGHT}

    playerObj['rect'] = pygame.Rect( (playerObj['x'], playerObj['y'], playerObj['size'], playerObj['size']) )

    while True:
        DISPLAY_SURFACE.fill(COLOR)
        DISPLAY_SURFACE.blit(playerObj['surface'], playerObj['rect'])
        for event in pygame.event.get():

            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_UP:
                    moveUp = True

            if event.type == KEYUP:
                if event.key == K_UP:
                    moveUp = False

            elif event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

        if moveUp:
            playerObj['rect'].y -= movement
            print("moving up")

        else:
            print('stopped')

        pygame.display.update()
        FPS_CLOCK.tick(FPS)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It works, I tried it myself. But you sould refactor your code, no need to carry along the initial x,y, etc. values in your dictionary.

**EDIT**
With movement in all four directions this would be:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

FPS = 30


WIN_WIDTH = 800
WIN_HEIGHT = 600
HALF_WIDTH = int(WIN_WIDTH / 2)
HALF_HEIGHT = int(WIN_HEIGHT / 2)

COLOR = (255, 0, 255)
IMAGE = pygame.image.load('squirrel.png')
STARTSIZE = 25

LEFT = 'left'

def move_rect(rect, key, distance):
    if key == K_UP: 
        rect.y-=distance
    elif key == K_DOWN: 
        rect.y+=distance
    elif key == K_LEFT: 
        rect.x-=distance
    elif key == K_RIGHT: 
        rect.x+=distance

def main():
    pygame.init()
    FPS_CLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
    movement = 1

    key2mvmt = {K_UP:False, K_DOWN:False, K_LEFT:False, K_RIGHT:False}

    DISPLAY_SURFACE = pygame.display.set_mode((WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT))

    playerObj = {'surface': pygame.transform.scale(IMAGE, (STARTSIZE, STARTSIZE)),
                     'facing': LEFT,
                     'size': STARTSIZE,
                     'x': HALF_WIDTH,
                     'y': HALF_HEIGHT}

    playerObj['rect'] = pygame.Rect( (playerObj['x'], playerObj['y'], playerObj['size'], playerObj['size']) )

    while True:
        DISPLAY_SURFACE.fill(COLOR)
        DISPLAY_SURFACE.blit(playerObj['surface'], playerObj['rect'])
        for event in pygame.event.get():

            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if key2mvmt.has_key(event.key):
                    key2mvmt[event.key]= True

            if event.type == KEYUP:
                if key2mvmt.has_key(event.key):
                    key2mvmt[event.key]= False

            elif event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

        for k in key2mvmt.keys():
            if key2mvmt[k]:
                move_rect(playerObj['rect'], k, movement)

        else:
            print('stopped')

        pygame.display.update()
        FPS_CLOCK.tick(FPS)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```